# Dynamically Changing MaskedCheckbox Mask

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a masked textbox which I use to force users to use a specific format for telephone numbers.

Because there are numerous formats for telephone numbers I wish to include a "catch-all" type selection for the mask.

Here is the idea:

I use a combobox with the various format options:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="LContactNumberFormat" SelectionChanged="LContactNumberFormat_SelectionChanged">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="+27" FontFamily="Arial Nova"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="+44" FontFamily="Arial Nova"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="000" FontFamily="Arial Nova"/>
</ComboBox>
```

So a user would select the specific option from the dropdown which would set the mask of the Maskedtextbox (where option "000" is the "catch-all" option I referred to):

[Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3YBU.png)

So the maskedtextbox's mask changes based off the combobox selection:

```
         private void LContactNumberFormat_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            string temp;
            if (LContactNumberFormat.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                
                ComboBoxItem cbi = (ComboBoxItem)LContactNumberFormat.SelectedItem;
                temp = cbi.Content.ToString(); //save the combobox selection as a string to insert in the mask

                
                LUserTelephoneNumber.Mask = $"{temp} 000000000"; //update textbox mask based off selection
                
            }
        }
```

This approach seems to work initially, however when changing from the "000" option to either the "+27" or "+44" version I get the following error:

**System.ArgumentException: 'The mask cannot be applied to the current text. (Parameter 'Mask')'**

(Note this does not happen when changing between the "+27" and "+44" versions)
Further note this happens only if I have entered a number in the texbox and THEN try to change the format.

Answer (score 0):

Well I feel stupid, but I simply had to set the textbox text to null when changing between the options.

This seems to fix the issue:

```
private void LContactNumberFormat_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    LUserTelephoneNumber.Text = null; // <---- Fix
    string temp;
    if (LContactNumberFormat.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        //ComboBoxItem cbi1 = (ComboBoxItem)(sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem;
        ComboBoxItem cbi = (ComboBoxItem)LContactNumberFormat.SelectedItem;
        temp = cbi.Content.ToString(); //save the combobox selection as a string to insert in the mask

        LUserTelephoneNumber.IsEnabled = true;
        LUserTelephoneNumber.Mask = $"{temp} 000000000";
    }
}
```

I will leave this open in case anyone ever has a blunder like me.